# React Hooks (useCallback и useMemo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Товарищи.. Возникла проблема, не могу понять фишки хуков useCallback и UseMemo. Читал уже доку и пару разных статей, но нет четкой картины для чего это нужно, какая от этого польза, в какой фазе это происходит. Буду признателен за любое доходчивое объяснение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Хук `useCallback`

Давайте напишем самую простую функцию счетчик.

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>counter: {count}</p>
      <button 
      onClick={_ => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>
        increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Добавим туда функцию, которая выводит на консоль текст

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const helloConsole = _ => {
    console.log("hi chaps :)");
  };
  helloConsole();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>counter: {count}</p>
      <button 
      onClick={_ => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>
        increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Теперь при каждом увеличении счетчика это функция `helloConsole` будет заново создаваться.
То есть

Первый render

```
function App() {
  const count = 0; 

  const helloConsole = _ => {
    console.log("hi chaps :)");
  };
  helloConsole();
  //...
```

Второй render

```
function App() {
  const count = 1; 

  const helloConsole = _ => {
    console.log("hi chaps :)");
  };
  helloConsole();
  //...
```

Третий render

```
function App() {
  const count = 2; 

  const helloConsole = _ => {
    console.log("hi chaps :)");
  };
  helloConsole();
  //...
```

И функция `helloConsole` из первого render-а НЕ равен функции из второго render-а и т.д. При каждом рендере создаётся новая функция `helloConsole` с новой ссылкой.

```
// 1 count -------  2 count  //         
helloConsole !== helloConsole
```

И тут надо подумать что будет если на реальном проекте у вас будет такая функция которая каждый раз пересоздаётся и внутри 500 строк кода делает определенные вычисления. Я думаю производительность этого компонента упадет.И даже в зависимости от ситуации и кода можно будет заметить это невооруженным глазом.

> Решение `useCallback`

Надо обернуть вашу функцию в `useCallback` и добавить массив зависимостей.

```
  const anyFunc = useCallback(() => {
    // 500 строк кода
  }, [dependencies]);
```

**ВАЖНЫЕ ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ**

1.Не надо использовать `useCallback` без массива зависимостей.

```
  const anyFunc = useCallback(() => {
    // любой код
  }, []);
```

Так писать НЕ надо. Тут вы больше потеряете чем, получите. Если нет массива зависимостей просто напишите функцию за пределы компонента. Как то так.

```
  const anyFunc = () => {
    // любой код
  };

function App () { // наш компонент
```

Этот код идентичен `useCallback` без массива зависимостей. Советую использовать именно второй подход если массив `useCallback` пустой.

2.Не надо использовать useCallback везде где можно использовать.

```
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    // обработать события клика 
  }, []);
```

Опять же в таком коде вы потеряете больше чем, получите. Ваш компонент станет медленнее.

Вот [**тут**](https://codesandbox.io/s/0y7wm3pp1w) можно посмотреть как работает компонент с и без `useCallback`

### Хук `useMemo`

В отличие от `useCallback` которой мемоизирует только коллбэки `useMemo` мемоизирует все.

```
const List = React.useMemo(() =>
  listOfItems.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    itemProp1: expensiveFunction(props.first),
    itemProp2: anotherPriceyFunction(props.second)
  })), [listOfItems]
)
```

Пример взят [**отсюда**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-usememo)

В этом случае `useMemo` возвращает массив.

В ссылке наверху который я указал написано

> If you implement useMemo too often in an application, it can **harm** the
> performance.

Если вы будете использовать `useMemo` часто  это может нанести вред по быстродействии приложения.

Это значит второе замечание которое я написал наверху для `useCallback` актуально и для `useMemo`.

Также если вы попытаетесь мемоизировать коллбэк в useMemo это будет идентично использованию [**useCallback**](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

```
useCallback(fn, deps) — это эквивалент useMemo(() => fn, deps).
```

##### [Update](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%91%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%20children%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.4&oq=%D0%91%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%20children%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.4&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCDEyNjBqMGoxqAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Бывают случаи, когда оптимизация не будет работать, например когда мы передаем в качестве `children` другой компонент.

```
// Здесь мемоизация не работает
<MemoizedComponent>
  <div />
<MemoizedComponent>

// И здесь мемоизация тоже не работает
<MemoizedComponent>
  <MyOtherComponent />
<MemoizedComponent>

// мемоизация сработает с примитивами
<MemoizedComponent>
  строка
<MemoizedComponent>
<MemoizedComponent>
  {123}
<MemoizedComponent>
<MemoizedComponent>
  {true}
<MemoizedComponent>

// или надо мемоизировать дочерний компонент
const memoChild = useMemo(() => <div />, []);
<MemoizedComponent>
  {memoChild}
<MemoizedComponent>

const memoChild = useMemo(() => <MyOtherComponent />, []);
<MemoizedComponent>
  {memoChild}
<MemoizedComponent>
```

Answer (score 1):

`useCallback` запоминает функцию и не пересоздаёт её заново в целях оптимизации.

`useMemo` запоминает значение и не пересчитывает его (сложные математические вычисления), также для оптимизации.

Применяется в зависимости от того что нужно: функция или значение.